# could not figure out uiview transitions used in yahoo weather app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uianimation

I was trying to mimic the yahoo weather app screen transition between cities, I couldn't figure out what transition it is. Any clue?

I really appreciate you time.
Thanks

Edit:

I have slideView ctrler which has a subview. The sliderview has an image and the subview has text. When I make a swipe, the text view with text must be moving and dragging way the view ctrler with it at a slower rate and this intern should start dragging in the next view ctrler which is an instance of slider Ctrler.

Comment: Not everyone uses the Yahoo weather app (which could also change). Add a picture or two or better describe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in transition that does this for you (I assume you're talking about the images that are transitioning their `frame`/`center` at a different rate than the view itself). You'd probably have to write it yourself. Some basic familiarity with gesture recognizers and view animation is needed.

The basic effect is by simultaneously adjusting the `center` property for two image views as you change the `frame` of those views (or their super views). (Or, you can achieve this by having image views whose `contentMode` is `UIViewContentModeCenter` and just changing the `frame`.) I'd suggest you start with some simple tests of the effect and build from there.

For example, I created a scene that has two image views, whose autolayout constraints were defined as follows:

```
H:|[leftImageView][rightImageView]|
V:|[leftImageView]|
V:|[rightImageView]|
```

I then defined a width constraint for the `leftImageView`, and hooked it up to an `IBOutlet` for that constraint, e.g. `leftImageWidthConstraint`. I then have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that could handle the gesture, simply changing this `leftImageWidthConstraint` accordingly (and with auto layout, the rest of the frame is calculated automatically for me from that):

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint translate = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
    static CGFloat width;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        width = self.leftImageWidthConstraint.constant;
    }

    CGFloat newWidth = width + translate.x;

    if (newWidth < 0)
        newWidth = 0;
    else if (newWidth > self.view.bounds.size.width)
        newWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;

    self.leftImageWidthConstraint.constant = newWidth;

    // if you let go, animate the views to their final position

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // if more than half way, set left view's target width to take up full width, 
        // otherwise set left view's target width to zero

        if (newWidth > (self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0))
            newWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
        else
            newWidth = 0;

        // animate the changing of the constraint (and thus the `frame`) accordingly

        self.leftImageWidthConstraint.constant = newWidth;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Thus, as I pan across, the two images are centered within their clipped frames:

[image]

This is a very basic implementation of the idea. There are, though, a ton of implementation details (custom container vs subviews, autolayout vs not, etc.), so until you answer some of those questions, it's going to be hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer. This is the direction I am going. I though I need be using attachment behavior. I have edited the answer with detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

It is not default but i achieved similar to it in my old app

1. Register gesture on your view and on detection set `isFromLeftSide` accordingly
2. Call following. do fine tune this as per your requirements

   ```
    [self.view addSubview:mySlidingView];
           mySlidingView.frame = // set offscreen frame, in the direction you want it to appear from depending on flag isFromLeftSide
           [UIView animateWithDuration:8.0 
                            animations:^{
                                mySlidingView.frame = // desired end location
                                   }];
   ```